# Âncora Jquery extremamente precisa!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<?php       
   foreach($sqlPortfolio2 as $dPortfolio2):
    echo '<li><a href="#guia'.$dPortfolio2['id'].'" class="scroll">'.$dPortfolio2['nome'.$lg].'</a></li>';
                endforeach;
                ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
   });
});
</script>
```

O problema é que eu uso o menu fixo, ou seja, quando eu clico em um item do menu, o menu vem junto, e acaba ficando por cima do título do elemento que eu cliquei! Tem como fazer uma âncora extremamente precisa?

Comment: posta seu html para eu ver o que esta acontecendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve descontar a altura do menu ao realizar o scroll.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - $("#MENU").outerHeight(true) - 20}, 800);
   });
});
</script>
```

Descontamos 20 pixels para que o menu não fique "grudado" no elemento mais ao topo. Assim fica visualmente mais agradável.

Comment: Essa #MENU tem que estar configurado uma height no css dela?

Comment: @user3081 Não, esse #MENU é o Id do seu menu (troque pelo id do seu menu). Esse código vai pegar o height real do seu menu (altura dele) independente de você ter explicitado isso no CSS ou não.

Comment: funcionou! Mas o menu fica colado ao título, tem como determinar uma altura, ao invés de ser automático?

Comment: @user3081 o que acontece é que foi descontada a exata altura do menu, por isso fica colado. Você pode descontar mais uns 20 pixels para que fique visualmente mais agradável.

Comment: veja minha edição da resposta.

Comment: @user3081 você pode determinar uma altura fixa sim, no lugar do código que pegamos a altura do menu pode ser uma valor fixo, porém não recomendo fazer isso, pois se algum dia você mudar a altura do menu vai ter que lembrar de alterar esse código também. É muito mais simples e melhor fazer como eu demonstrei na última edição da resposta. Pegue o tamanho total do menu e desconte mais um valor fixo de pixels (no caso 20)

Comment: Muito obrigado Erick Gallani! Deu certinho! Valeu mesmo!!!