# Ajustar ancoragem para outra página com menu fixo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Oi. Tenho um site com menu fixado no topo. Na home, eu tenho links que devem ancorar Id's de páginas internas do site. Por mais que a ancoragem funcione, parte do conteúdo fica atrás do menu fixo, então eu precisava ajeitar isso, de modo que funcionasse quando ocorre o jump de uma página pra outra.

Fuçando em vários lugares, inclusive em perguntas semelhantes aqui no Stack Overflow, cheguei num código que, a princípio, resolveria meu problema, mas ele não funciona.

Meu **HTML**:

```
<a href="http://localhost/meu_site/psicologia#psicoterapia" class="psi-block-item"></a>
```

Meu **JavaScript**:

```
<script src="http://localhost/meu_site/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

$('.psi-block-item').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(this).attr("href")
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top-100 }, 100)
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

Esse código, a princípio, funciona redondo se o id pro qual quero ancorar estiver na mesma página da âncora, ou seja, na home. Mas **não funciona quando ele é um id dentro de uma página interna**. Aparentemente, ao pular pra outra página, ele parece ignorar o animate do JavaScript, e apenas segue o href da tag .

Vi alguns lugarem sugerirem uso de pseudo elementos do CSS de forma a fazer eles existirem, mas escondidos. Não quero desmerecer nenhum método, mas eu queria uma solução mais profissional, que me fizesse aprender, e não algo mais no estilo da gambiarra. Por isso estou recorrendo a criar esse tópico.

Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Âncora Jquery extremamente precisa!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87644/%c3%82ncora-jquery-extremamente-precisa)

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa. A pergunta que você postou aqui, a princípio, resolve o problema se o id de destino da ancoragem estiver dentro da mesma página. No entanto, ele deixa de funcionar se o id está dentro de uma outra página, uma página interna.

@edit, inclusive, se for ver meu código, ele é praticamente igual ao da resposta dessa pergunta. Eu já considerei descontar o valor de altura do menu, como o usuário que respondeu essa pergunta disse. Não dá certo quando o id está em uma outra página do site.